# Use sort function multiple times in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

Right now I have a table with some data from the github api.
In the table you can click on the Stars heading and it sorts the list from 0 to *.
My function works for one column. But how can I use this function over and over again for different columns?

My table headings :

```
<th>Name</th>
<th onClick={this.sortList}>Stars</th>

{* This should update value forks_count *}
<th onClick={this.sortList}>Forks</th>
```

My function:

What I do is I get my array and sort it based on stargazers_count. This works, however when I want to sort my Forks count.. stargazers_count should be forks_count. Is this possible?

```
sortList = () => {
    const items = this.props.repos;

    items.sort(function (a, b) {
        //stargazers_count should be forks_count when I click on forks heading
        return a.stargazers_count - b.stargazers_count;
    });

    this.setState({
        repos: items
    })

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With closures:

```
<th>Name</th>
<th onClick={this.sortListBy("stargazers_count")}>Stars</th>

{* This should update value forks_count *}
<th onClick={this.sortListBy("forks_count")}>Forks</th>



sortListBy = (prop) => () => {
    const items = this.props.repos;

    items.sort(function (a, b) { 
        return a[prop] - b[prop];
    });

    this.setState({
        repos: items
    })

};
```

Comment: All of them works but I like this one the most. It's short and simple, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Have an array of objects as configuration:

```
fields = [{ name: 'Stars', field: 'stargazers_count'}, { name: 'Forks', field: 'forks_count' }]
```

Now, have your `th` rendered inside a `fields.map` function something like this

```
fields.map(f => <th onClick={() => this.sortList(f.field)}> {f.name} </th>)
```

This will render all `th` according to your config array.

Now change your `sortList` function such that it takes field as a parameter.

```
sortList = (field) => {
...

items.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[field] - b[field];
});

...

};
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible using `bind` and taking the column name as argument like following :

```
<th>Name</th>
<th onClick={this.sortList.bind(this, 'stargazers_count')}>Stars</th>

{* This should update value forks_count *}
<th onClick={this.sortList.bind(this, 'forks_count')}>Forks</th>
```

---

```
sortList = (column) => {
    const items = this.props.repos;

    items.sort(function (a, b) {
        //stargazers_count should be forks_count when I click on forks heading
        return a[column] - b[column];
    });

    this.setState({
        repos: items
    })

};
```

Comment: @JustinTime On which parameter ?

Comment: On column in the function

Comment: @JustinTime Well you can see it is used right here : `a[column]`